# command history with correct time stamps in unix

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, history, timestamp

I want to schedule a program that display history of a remote machine and stores it in a file in the local machine with timestamps(i.e which commands were executed when)
The code i used is this:

```
ssh -i private_key user@ip 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT=\"%D-%T \" ; \
                            export HISTFILE=/home/$user/.bash_history; \
                            set -o history; history' > myfile.txt
```

But instead of giving the correct time stamps it puts the present time in front of every command. So if the scheduler runs at say 9 o clock the time stamp for every command is 9 o clock.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `BASHTIMEFORMAT` isn't set in a session, the timing information is not saved to the history file (otherwise it is saved as a comment in there).

So unless the user you're trying to log has that in his/her environment, you will not get timing information. It is simply not recorded, so impossible to retrieve.

Comment: So it would be worth adding `export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%D-%T "` to the /home/$user/.bashrc file on the remote host.  This is run when the user logs in and will cause history to save the timestamps, so you should get your desired output.

Comment: yeah i added HISTTIMEFORMAT line to the .bashrc file, still not getting timestamps. What do the lines starting with hash mean? are those timestamps of some sort?

Comment: Yes, the `#123123` are the timestamps.

Comment: @Mat. Supposing i want to login as root and get the history of various users with timestamps. Or in other words i want their histories to be written in their .bash_history files with timestamps . what do i do?

Comment: How do i set BASHTIMEFORMAT? where do i set it?

Comment: You could set that in /etc/profile or wherever global environment configuration is done on your system, but users will always be able to unset it (or unset history altogether, or delete their history files whenever they want). I don't know of a way to spy on users like that with standard tools/shells.

Comment: i logged in as root and set the bashtimeformat for a particular user in his /etc/profile. i also exported HISTFILE as ~/.bash_history. when i do cat ~/.bash_history i still get #tags instead of time stamps

Comment: The `history` command translates the timestamps to the format string you specified. The files themselves will only contain the timestamp.

Comment: oh. history command translates it. Hmm nice. Didnt know that. So is there any way i could be able to convert these hashed timestamps to my desired format via a script?

Comment: Yes, you use the history command in a script, or use `date` do to the conversion, but that's a completely different question.

Comment: aah k different question .. different thread. :D. thanks for the help mat, but this still hasnt solved my problem. dont mind if i dont accept the answer :(

Comment: As I said, you can accept (or not) whatever you want. But I don't see why you say this doesn't solve your problem. Once history time information is recorded, `history` displays it. If history time isn't recorded, it doesn't. It's as simple as that.